React(Vite) web app runs on localhost but when I deploy it to vercel, I get a blank page
When I try to access the website from my browser I get this error in the console:
index-3d1f8e86.js:126  Uncaught TypeError: fw.div is not a function at index-3d1f8e86.js:126:916 and blank page.
When I try to check logs on vercel I get none.
I have git repository with the folder structure which looks like this:

My vercel.json file is found in the client folder and looks like this:
{
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "/(.*)",
        "destination": "/"
      }
    ]
  }

Vite.config.js file also resides in the client folder and it looks like this:
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
export default {
  content: [
    "./index.html",
    "./src/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      colors: {
        'light-blue-primary': '#4AC9FF',
        'light-blue-secondary':'#1098F7',
        'dark-blue-primary': '#001F3F',
        'dark-blue-secondary': '#0059A3',
        'light-green-primary': '#77D353',
        'light-green-secondary': '#47A620',
        'dark-green-primary': '#217F24',
        'dark-green-secondary': '#3EAB4D',
      },
      fontFamily:{
        titleFont: ['Poppins', 'sans-serif']
      }
    },
  },
  plugins: [],
}

During deployment I chose build framework to be "Vite" and the root directory to be WEB-DEVELOPMENT/web-app/client. I left other things to be default.
Can someone please help me figure out how I will solve the problem?

Where does you bundle get generated? In /web-development/web-app/client?

@mssp, yes in the client folder

Based on index-3d1f8e86.js:126  Uncaught TypeError: fw.div is not a function at index-3d1f8e86.js:126:916, I think it might be a node version issue. I am not sure what are the default settings in Vercel, I know I had a similar issue with Netlify where for some reason would use node12 by default which is ancient at this point. Try to match your local node -v on Vercel as well
